# Reselect Pandas dataframe from specific index

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe that I'd like to "reselect", for lack of a better term, using an index.

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
   1    |    2    |    3
   4    |    5    |    6
Data    |         |  
Header  | Header2 | Header3
   7    |    8    |    9
```

I'd like to select this dataframe but specifically at index `4,0` so that it looks like:

```
Header  | Header2 | Header3
   7    |    8    |    9
```

I know I can do something like

```
df.iloc[[4,5], [0,1,2]]
```

But the problem with that is I don't always know where this index will be in each dataframe, the only information I'll have is the index of the value I'd like to start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future travelers, I ended up doing this in a somewhat strange manner. First I got the columns I was interested in:

```
columns = [x for x in df.iloc[4].values.flatten().tolist() if str(x) != 'nan']
```

Then I sliced the data that I know I need:

```
data = df.iloc[5:, 0:2].values
```

And finally created a new dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Where I set columns, the `4` is the index of the row that the columns are on (the number I already knew). When I set data,, `5:` signifies all data from row 5 and beyond (since I didn't know where it ended), and `0:2` is columns 1-3.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works for what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
df[df["Column1"]=="Data"].index.item()
```

You'll receive the index for the location of the row where "Data" is located. From there you can use df.iloc to locate the data you're looking for.

Comment: While that does work to get the index, I already have the index. I need to create a new dataframe from an existing one, along with new columns.